# After updating to 10.6.5, the About this Mac still show 10.6.4

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

Today I update my 10.6.4 to 10.6.5. After the update, rebooted, About this Mac stills show 10.6.4. Did anyone have similar issue?

Comment: Try running the 10.6.5 combo updater.

Comment: The link to the combo updater: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1324

Comment: Does the problem persist after running the combo updater?

Comment: I found a fix on Apple discussion: http://ho.race.hk/blog/?p=351 http://discussions.apple.com/post!reply.jspa?messageID=12565123